# How do I transform Mongodb Extended json into json format like good json using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb

I have to get data from mongodb using python. I use pymongo to get data and I can get the data in the json format. But, I think it is called like Mongodb Extended Json like

[
    {
        "no": 0,
        "isMain": false,
        "parent": null,
        "defaultLanguage": {
            "$oid": "584067f3102e1f03d60d67da"
        }
    }
]

I would like to have that like

[
    {
        "no": 0,
        "isMain": false,
        "parent": null,
        "defaultLanguage": "584067f3102e1f03d60d67da"
    }
]

But I could not find that transformation.

I have used bson.json_util in order to get that json but could not go further anymore. Also, I have tried to use mongoengine_goodjson.GoodJSONEncoder but could not succeed.

```
import pymongo
import pprint
import os
import urllib
import json
import mongoengine_goodjson as gj
import bson

from datetime import datetime as dt
from bson import json_util, ObjectId
from bson.json_util import dumps, RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS, STRICT_JSON_OPTIONS


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
host = "xxxhost"
port = 27017
dbname = "xxxdb"
authdb = "admin"
username = urllib.parse.quote("root")
password = urllib.parse.quote("xxxpass")


def getdata(username, password, host, port, dbname, authdb, tablenamelist):
    connection_string = 'mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?authSource={}'.format(username, password, host, port, dbname, authdb)
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
    mydb = myclient[dbname]
    for elem in mydb.list_collection_names():
        mycols = mydb[elem]
        print('tablename:', elem)
        with open(dir_path+'/'+elem+'.json','w') as f:
            dump = dumps([doc for doc in mycols.find({},{ "_id": 0})], sort_keys=False, indent=4, default=json_util.default, json_options=RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS)
            f.write(dump)
        f.close()

getdata(username, password, host, port, dbname, authdb, tablenames)
```

How can I transform it?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You must do so manually.  Here is a quick example of what happens with the 3 different output formats:

```
#  This is the native python BigDecimal...                                      
pythonDecimal = Decimal("923.2")

# ...but it doesn't work with BSON; you must convert:                           
bsonDecimal = decimal128.Decimal128(pythonDecimal)

db.foo.insert({
    "intVal": 1,
        "longVal": 23L,
    "floatVal": 3.14159,
        "dateVal": datetime.datetime.now(),
        "decimalVal": bsonDecimal
})

doc1 = db.foo.find_one()
print doc1

for fmt in RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS,STRICT_JSON_OPTIONS,CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS:
    print fmt, dumps(doc1, sort_keys=False, indent=4, default=json_util.default , json_options=fmt)

{u'longVal': 23L, u'floatVal': 3.14159, u'intVal': 1, u'decimalVal': Decimal128('923.2'), u'_id': ObjectId('5db5d175283c3277b32f068e'), u'dateVal': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 13, 18, 45, 269000)}
JSONOptions(strict_number_long=False, datetime_representation=2, strict_uuid=True, json_mode=1, document_class=dict, tz_aware=True, uuid_representation=PYTHON_LEGACY, unicode_decode_error_handler='strict', tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x1104142d0>) {
    "longVal": 23, 
    "floatVal": 3.14159, 
    "intVal": 1, 
    "decimalVal": {
        "$numberDecimal": "923.2"
    }, 
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5db5d175283c3277b32f068e"
    }, 
    "dateVal": {
        "$date": "2019-10-27T13:18:45.269Z"
    }
}
JSONOptions(strict_number_long=True, datetime_representation=2, strict_uuid=True, json_mode=0, document_class=dict, tz_aware=True, uuid_representation=PYTHON_LEGACY, unicode_decode_error_handler='strict', tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x1104142d0>) {
    "longVal": {
        "$numberLong": "23"
    }, 
    "floatVal": 3.14159, 
    "intVal": 1, 
    "decimalVal": {
        "$numberDecimal": "923.2"
    }, 
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5db5d175283c3277b32f068e"
    }, 
    "dateVal": {
        "$date": "2019-10-27T13:18:45.269Z"
    }
}
JSONOptions(strict_number_long=True, datetime_representation=1, strict_uuid=True, json_mode=2, document_class=dict, tz_aware=True, uuid_representation=PYTHON_LEGACY, unicode_decode_error_handler='strict', tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x1104142d0>) {
    "longVal": {
        "$numberLong": "23"
    }, 
    "floatVal": {
        "$numberDouble": "3.14159"
    }, 
    "intVal": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
    }, 
    "decimalVal": {
        "$numberDecimal": "923.2"
    }, 
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5db5d175283c3277b32f068e"
    }, 
    "dateVal": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1572182325269"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, none of the output types attempt to "simplify" the output of `decimal`, `datetime`, or `oid` types.   The `JSONOptions` class provides no further options to adjust these representations.   You must "manually" turn these into a simplified (and potentially lossy form).  Below is quick example:

```
def emitThing(v):
    if v.__class__.__name__ == 'dict':
        emitDict(v)
    elif v.__class__.__name__ == 'list':
        emitList(v)
    else:
        if v.__class__.__name__ in {'Int64','int','long','float','decimal','Decimal128','Decimal'}:
            print str(v),
        elif v.__class__.__name__ == 'datetime':
            print '"%s"' % v.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
        else:
            print '"%s"' % str(v),

def emitList(ll):
    print "[",
    first = True
    for v in ll:
        if not first:
            print ",",
        emitThing(v)
        first = False
    print "]",

def emitDict(dd):
    print "{",
    first = True
    for k, v in dd.iteritems():
        if not first:
            print ",",
        print '"%s":' % k,
        emitThing(v)
        first = False
    print "}",

emitDict(doc1)
```

Comment: There are dozens of tables to import into sql server. In order not to write sql server scripts of json for all tables, I would like to do it automatically using python. I think, there is no solution yet according to my desire, am I right?

Comment: Quick doc-to-JSON example added above.